# Issue in setup of custom retriever in Langchain using BaseRetriever object has no field "vectorstore"

Tags: python-3.x, langchain, chromadb

I have the following code which should take a document and create a series of questions based on it. I then want to embed these questions into a ChromaDB vector store and the parent docs in Langchain document that persists to disk along with the vectorstore. However, I get an error raised:
ValueError: "QuestionRetriever" object has no field "vectorstore"

My code:

```
class QuestionRetriever(BaseRetriever):
        def __init__(self, vectorstore, docstore):
            super().__init__()
            self.vectorstore = vectorstore
            self.docstore = docstore
        
        def _get_relevant_documents(self, query, run_manager):
            # Placeholder implementation, can be updated later to return actual results
            return []

        def add_documents(self, parent_docs):
            for parent_doc in parent_docs:
                # Generate hypothetical questions for each parent document
                questions = generate_questions_for_document(llm, parent_doc.page_content)

                # Process and clean the generated questions
                split_questions = [q.strip() + '?' for q in questions.split('?') if q.strip()]

                # Create Document objects for each question
                question_docs = [Document(page_content=question) for question in split_questions]

                # Add each question document to the vectorstore
                self.vectorstore.add_documents(question_docs)

                # Store parent document in the docstore with a linkage to its questions
                parent_doc_id = self.docstore.add_document(parent_doc)
                for question_doc in question_docs:
                    question_doc.metadata['parent_doc_id'] = parent_doc_id

    def store_questions(llm, new_docs, chroma_db_path, local_file_store_path):
        # Instantiate the Embeddings model
        model_name = "BAAI/bge-large-en-v1.5"
        encode_kwargs = {'normalize_embeddings': True}

        bge_embeddings = HuggingFaceBgeEmbeddings(
            model_name=model_name,
            model_kwargs={'device': 'cuda'},
            encode_kwargs=encode_kwargs
        )

        # The vectorstore for indexing the documents
        vectorstore = Chroma(
            collection_name="full_documents_children",
            embedding_function=bge_embeddings,
            persist_directory=chroma_db_path
        )

        # The storage layer for the parent documents
        fs = LocalFileStore(local_file_store_path)
        store = create_kv_docstore(fs)

        # Initialize the custom retriever
        retriever = QuestionRetriever(vectorstore=vectorstore, docstore=store)

        # Add documents (and their questions) using the retriever
        retriever.add_documents(new_docs)

        print(f"Knowledge Base Creation complete for hypothetical questions")


    # Path to the folder containing the Knowledge base JSON files
    folder_path = '/home/adambooth/Downloads/jsons'

    # Set paths of the folders to be cleared
    chroma_db_path = 'data/chroma_db'
    local_file_store_path = 'data/doc_store'
   
    # Remove existing Vectorstore
    clear_folder(chroma_db_path) # Remove existing DB 
    clear_folder(local_file_store_path) # Remove existing documnet store

    #Create new Vectorstore
    new_docs = create_docs() # Loads and parses the JSON in correct document format
    store_children(new_docs) # Embeds children in vectorstore and parent documents as Langhain document store
    store_questions(llm, new_docs, chroma_db_path, local_file_store_path) # Embeds hypothetical questions in the vectorstore and parent documents as Langchain document store
```

I have tried referring to the support docs on the Langchain website but I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and finally figured it out.
you should not use the init method, instead pass the fields directly to you custom retriever.

```
class QuestionRetriever(BaseRetriever):

    vectorestore:VectorStore
    docstore:Docstore
    
    def _get_relevant_documents(self, query, run_manager):
        # Placeholder implementation, can be updated later to return actual results
        return []

    def add_documents(self, parent_docs):
        for parent_doc in parent_docs:
            # Generate hypothetical questions for each parent document
            questions = generate_questions_for_document(llm, parent_doc.page_content)

            # Process and clean the generated questions
            split_questions = [q.strip() + '?' for q in questions.split('?') if q.strip()]

            # Create Document objects for each question
            question_docs = [Document(page_content=question) for question in split_questions]

            # Add each question document to the vectorstore
            self.vectorstore.add_documents(question_docs)

            # Store parent document in the docstore with a linkage to its questions
            parent_doc_id = self.docstore.add_document(parent_doc)
            for question_doc in question_docs:
                question_doc.metadata['parent_doc_id'] = parent_doc_id

def store_questions(llm, new_docs, chroma_db_path, local_file_store_path):
    # Instantiate the Embeddings model
    model_name = "BAAI/bge-large-en-v1.5"
    encode_kwargs = {'normalize_embeddings': True}
```

then to initialise your object

```
custom_retriever = QuestionRetriever(vectorstore=vectorstore, docstore=docstore)
```